# Minimal normal subgroup of a finite perfect group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite perfect group, $N$ is an Abelian minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and $$G/N=SL_2(q),$$ where $q=2^f$ for some integer $f\geq5$.

What can we say about the order of $N$?

Thanks!

Comment: There are no perfect central extensions of this form. So you are asking for the dimensions of the nontrivial  irreducible modules of ${\rm SL}_2(q)$ over prime fields. Those are certainly known.

Comment: @Derek Holt, thanks for your comment. Could you please introduce a reference for irreducible modules of SL2(q) over prime fields?